# Join 3 boolean columns into 1 taking into account the row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Be the following DataFrame in pandas:

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 | Column_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 82198 | True | False | False | red |
| 27498 | False | False | False | red |
| 84838 | False | False | True | red |
| 10498 | False | True | False | red |

I want to create a `New_column` that has the value True if any of the columns `Column_2`, `Column_3`, `Column_4` is True and False, if all 3 are false. Output example:

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 | Column_5 | New_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 82198 | True | False | False | red | True |
| 27498 | False | False | False | red | False |
| 84838 | False | False | True | red | True |
| 10498 | False | True | False | red | True |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works i think :

```
df["New_Column"] = df.Column_2 |df.Column_3| df.Column_4
```

Answer (score 0):

this might work:

```
df['new_column']=(df['Column_2']==True) | (df['Column_3']==True) | (df['Column_4']==True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option:

```
df["New_Column"] = df["Column_2"] |df["Column_3"]| df["Column_4"]
```